# Multiple regex capture groups in Nancy routes

Tags: c#, iis, nancy

I might be missing something obvious here, but I'm trying to define a route in NancyFx that uses multiple regex capture groups.

```
Get[@"/campaign/(?<campaignid>[0-9]{1,8})/console(?<page>[0-9])/(?<personid>[0-9]{1,8})"]
```

The regex works in the regex tester against URL's like `/campaign/12345/console1/123` but in Nancy I always get 404.

If I chop it down I get back to `Get[@"/campaign/(?<campaignid>[0-9]{1,8})/console"]` at which point it works, making me think that the problem might be having more than one named group. Is this meant to work, by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically what you are experience is a (new) bug that is happening because your middle capture group has a string literal in front of it. I'll have a look at that for the next, release which is just around the corner.

Fortunately there is an easy work around, just update your path so it looks like this

`@"/campaign/(?<campaignid>[0-9]{1,8})/(?:console(?<page>[0-9]))/(?<personid>[0-9]{1,8})"`

And this will trick Nancy a bit, but not capture the `console` part :)